# New User badge on child metas

Tags: bug, new-users, per-site-meta, new-contributor-indicator

The new user badge is showing up on meta for users who really aren't new. In this case it was really obvious - turns out they've been on Stack Overflow for 5+ years, but maybe this is their first meta post.

I think it'd be clearer if child metas inherited someone's new user status from the main site.

[image: New contributor who isn't]

Comment: No, why? Meta sites are a beast on their own. it is very useful to know if a seasoned user is still learning the ropes on meta.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, but if a user has more than 10k rep and access to moderator tools...we trust them to not be "new" anymore.

Comment: I've come across too many "trusted"  users that can't make head or tails of a meta site.

Comment: There are people with over 50K whom ask for assistance about how the sites work - this occurs more than once a month. Each site has *some* differences and OT is a common problem. It's to *remind* potential readers, politely, of the CoC without being so blatant about it. A search of Meta would have turned up a dupe for this, but alas ...

Answer (score 10):

No.

Meta site is very different from its main site. Someone who is a long time member on a main site might find the meta site to be very different from what they know and need help adjusting no less than new user on a main site.

I prefer to leave it this way, and don't change it. Surely it's not a bug.